# DetoxRuntimeError after executing the Detox test command

Tags: android, ubuntu-18.04, detox

> `Detox test -c android.emu.debug`

This issue is reporting that it is not finding the device. But device is connected and it is recognised by system. Please any help on this.

Please find package.json file

> "detox": {
>       "configurations": {
>         "android.emu.debug": {
>           "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/staging/debug/app-debug.apk",
>           "build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..",
>           "type": "android.attached",
>           "device": {
>             "avdName": "56149225"
>           }
>         },
>         "android.emu.release": {
>           "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk",
>           "build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=release && cd ..",
>           "type": "android.emulator",
>           "device": {
>             "avdName": "56149225"
>           }
>         }
>       }   }

**Log**

```
detox[16824] ERROR: [DetoxExportWrapper.js/DETOX_INIT_ERROR] 
 DetoxRuntimeError: DetoxRuntimeError: Could not find 'undefined' on the currently ADB attached devices:

HINT: Make sure your device is connected.
You can also try restarting adb with 'adb kill-server && adb start-server'.

List of devices attached
56149225        device


    at AttachedAndroidDriver.acquireFreeDevice (/home/yajana/Documents/Detox/examples/mobile-client/node_modules/detox/src/devices/drivers/AttachedAndroidDriver.js:21:13)
    at async Device.prepare (/home/yajana/Documents/Detox/examples/mobile-client/node_modules/detox/src/devices/Device.js:20:22)
    at async Detox.init (/home/yajana/Documents/Detox/examples/mobile-client/node_modules/detox/src/Detox.js:72:5)
    at async Function._initializeInstance (/home/yajana/Documents/Detox/examples/mobile-client/node_modules/detox/src/DetoxExportWrapper.js:81:7)
    at async DetoxExportWrapper.init (/home/yajana/Documents/Detox/examples/mobile-client/node_modules/detox/src/DetoxExportWrapper.js:32:20)
    at async Context.<anonymous> (/home/yajana/Documents/Detox/examples/mobile-client/e2e/init.js:6:3)
  1) "before all" hook in "{root}"

  0 passing (39ms)
  1 failing

  1) "before all" hook in "{root}":
     Error: DetoxRuntimeError: Could not find 'undefined' on the currently ADB attached devices:

HINT: Make sure your device is connected.
You can also try restarting adb with 'adb kill-server && adb start-server'.

List of devices attached
56149225        device


      at AttachedAndroidDriver.acquireFreeDevice (node_modules/detox/src/devices/drivers/AttachedAndroidDriver.js:21:13)
      at async Device.prepare (node_modules/detox/src/devices/Device.js:20:22)
      at async Detox.init (node_modules/detox/src/Detox.js:72:5)
      at async Function._initializeInstance (node_modules/detox/src/DetoxExportWrapper.js:81:7)
      at async DetoxExportWrapper.init (node_modules/detox/src/DetoxExportWrapper.js:32:20)
      at async Context.<anonymous> (e2e/init.js:6:3)



detox[16816] ERROR: [cli.js] Error: Command failed: node_modules/.bin/mocha --opts e2e/mocha.opts --configuration android.emu.debug --grep :ios: --invert "e2e"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `"adbName" : <your-device-name>` instead of `"avdName"`.